# How to mining using GPU in private chain?

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, gpu, miner

Sir,
  We build a Ethereum private chain for one application.We use geth to mine and find the performance is not good. Geth use CPU to mine.So,what method I can use to mine using GPU? 
   Barkely

Answer (score 1):

cpp-ethereum is what I'm using.

```
$ cpp-ethereum -G -F http://localhost:8545
```

Make sure that geth is running with an "author" key specified.

But I am not sure it's working, so don't accept this answer until you confirm.  I can't find any good docs on cpp-ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information about your operating system an setup. Anyway, you can quickly test GPU mining by reading the official documentation.

[Here](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#gpu-mining), you can find the following example of GPU mining using ethminer:

```
geth account new // Set-up ethereum account if you do not have one

geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain localhost 2>> geth.log &

ethminer -G  // -G for GPU, -M for benchmark

tail -f geth.log
```